# Ambiguous Timer Behaviour

Tags: spring, spring-statemachine

I've a workflow where one of the state is supposed to do a status poll, so basically whenever I land in that state I want to run an action and then do the same every 'n' seconds until I get the expected response.

Following is the state machine config, START & INTERMEDIATE states are running in polling fashion ( retying till I get intended response )

```
        StateMachineBuilder.Builder<StateMachineConfig.States, StateMachineConfig.Events> builder =                       StateMachineBuilder.builder();

        builder.configureConfiguration()
                .withConfiguration()
                .machineId("Test-" + i)
                .taskScheduler(scheduler);

        builder.configureStates()
                .withStates()
                .initial(StateMachineConfig.States.START)
                .state(StateMachineConfig.States.START)
                .state(StateMachineConfig.States.INTERMEDIATE)
                .state(StateMachineConfig.States.STOP)
                .end(StateMachineConfig.States.STOP);

        builder.configureTransitions()
                .withExternal()
                .source(StateMachineConfig.States.START)
                .target(StateMachineConfig.States.START)
                .action(startAction)
                .timer(30000)
                .and()
                .withExternal()
                .source(StateMachineConfig.States.START)
                .target(StateMachineConfig.States.INTERMEDIATE)
                .event(StateMachineConfig.Events.GO1)
                .and()
                .withExternal()
                .source(StateMachineConfig.States.INTERMEDIATE)
                .target(StateMachineConfig.States.INTERMEDIATE)
                .timer(30000)
                .action(intermediateAction)
                .and()
                .withExternal()
                .source(StateMachineConfig.States.INTERMEDIATE)
                .target(StateMachineConfig.States.STOP)
                .event(StateMachineConfig.Events.GO2)
                .and()
                .withInternal()
                .source(StateMachineConfig.States.STOP)
                .action(stopAction);
        StateMachine stateMachine = builder.build();
        stateMachine.start();
```

The issue here is, as soon as state machine starts startAction runs, it sends the event GO1 which takes the state-machine to INTERMEDIATE, but the intermediateAction does not run immediately it waits for full 30 seconds before that, while the startAction does not do that.

I think the culprit being, both TimerTriggers are scheduled in doStart() in the initial phases of state-machine life cycle and both these triggers are processed as soon as we enter the START state. And when I get to the INTERMEDIATE state I do not have an '0th time' timer trigger event to process. Is this the intended behavior? If yes, how do I achieve this kind of functionality where I want to run an action every 'n' seconds including '0th time'

Repo to reproduce the issue: https://github.com/shethchintan7/spring-state-machine-thread-leak